# Remove Marker and Top Location From Google Map(Embedded IFrame)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-maps, iframe

I'm embedding google map into my site using IFrame. I did that successfully but need to hide the marker that pinpoints the location, and also the location-box at top-left corner of map. 
This is my IFrame:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="320" frameborder="0" style="border: 0"                                                       
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyCIAhb-
P3rzNhDdYYnqLaUxPiX6sJGA2lo&q=<%=RealAddress%>,<%=City%>,<%=State%>&nbsp;
<%=Zip%>"></iframe>
```

Link to Map Image: [Preview of Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvyKk.png)

Need to solve this quick please!

Comment: check out this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)

Comment: is there anything else we can do other than using google maps api?

Comment: Another option is geocode the address and use the [view mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#view_mode) of Maps Embed API.